# MVC - conversion issue with two models binding to the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I hope the holidays are good for all.

I am using MVC and connect to my db using ADO.net entity framework, so it created my entities for me.

I am trying to create a view that will use two models - Matchups and Players. The stored procs for each output lists which I will put under two tabs on the page. I found an article explaining a few different ways of binding two models to one view. After some effort, I have settled on ExpandoObject( ). However, I am getting the following error when I pull up my page:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 
'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you 
missing a cast?)
```

Here are are my model contexts:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<usp_GetMatchups_Result> usp_GetMatchups()
        {
            return 
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_GetMatchups_Result>("usp_GetMatchups");
        }

        public virtual ObjectResult<usp_GetAllNFLPlayers_Result> usp_GetAllPlayers()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_GetAllPlayers_Result>("usp_GetAllPlayers");
        }
```

My controller:

```
namespace SchmuckSports.Controllers
{
    public class MatchupController : Controller
    {
        TrinoviEntities db = new TrinoviEntities();

        public ActionResult MatchupList()
        {
            return View(db.usp_GetMatchups());
        }

        public ActionResult PLayerList()
        {
            return View(db.usp_GetAllPlayers());
        }

        public ActionResult FtblDashboard()
        {
            dynamic FTBL = new ExpandoObject();
            FTBL.Matchup = MatchupList() ;
            FTBL.Players = PLayerList();
            return View(FTBL);
        }
    }
}
```

And my view has this (omitted a bunch for simplicity sake, but let me know if you need more):

```
@model dynamic
@using SchmuckSports.Controllers;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Football Den";
}

<tbody>
      @foreach (var match in Model.Matchup)
          {
             <tr onclick="location.href= '@Url.Action("FtblDashboard", "Matchup", new { GameID = match.GameID })'">
                  <td>
                       @match.Date
                  </td>
                  <td>
                       @match.TeamAbbrev.Replace("&#x0D;", "<br />")
                  </td>
                  <td>
                       @match.Spread.Replace("&#x0D;", "<br />")
                  </td>
                  <td>
                       @match.Total.Replace("&#x0D;", "<br />")
                  </td>
                  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So what should I change in order to get the types to be the same? Sorry I'm not good enough with this syntax to find where exactly it's broke.

Thanks all for the assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MatchupList` returns a list wrapped into a view for some reason:

```
return View(db.usp_GetMatchups())
```

Which would only be needed if you used that as an MVC action. That does not seem to be the case - you seem to use it as a utility method for an actual action.

Given the simplicity of the MatchupList method, I would skip it altogether:

```
FTBL.Matchup = db.usp_GetMatchups();
```

It is not very clear what ObjectResult is, but assuming this is some sort of list, this should help you get rid of the exception.

Comment: Thank you very much for straightening that out. This did correct my error. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a model that contains what you want to render in your view instead of using `dynamic` so that your view will be strongly typed. Then you'll have intellisene, and the rest is much easier.

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public MatchupList Matchups {get;set;
    public PlayerList Players {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult FtblDashboard()
{
    var matchups = db.usp_GetMatchups();
    var players = db.usp_GetAllPlayers()
    var viewModel = new DashboardViewModel
        { Matchups = matchups, Players = players };        
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then begin your view with

```
@model DashboardViewModel
```

Now that everything is strongly typed the rest is easier. If you're displaying the data on different tabs you might also find it easier to create each tab as a separate partial view. That will keep each view smaller and more manageable.

There are valid reasons to use `dynamic`, but they don't come up often. Anything that can be strongly typed should be. That way you get your errors in the compiler. Otherwise you have to run the app, and if you did something really small like misspelling a property or referencing the wrong model you'll get a runtime error instead.

Comment: Yes thank you. I previously attempted the ViewModel, but ran into implicit conversion issues too so I moved to another option. I believe the issue was the same - I was still using the return view method. With suggestion to just get rid of it, I think this should work great as well.

Comment: I have a few questions with this. When trying to use the ViewModel, I am assuming  I ultimately still run into conversion issues since my MatchupList and PlayerList contoller methods return View() from my ADO.net generated entity data model with "ObjectResult" class:
    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_GetMatchups_Result> 
    
How would I change this syntax to just return the results of the "usp_GetMatchups" stored procedure to a generic list? And would a generic list be the best output?Hope my questions make sense. I'm new to this.

Comment: The `ObjectResult` class has a `GetList` method. That's going to return an `IList`. So you could change your model to an `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I changed my ViewModel properties to IEnumerable<T> as mentioned above and it works well. Many thanks!